# Create a toggle button with RxJS

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, togglebutton, rxjs

I'm pretty new to the concept of Reactive Programming, and I'm just playing around a bit. To practice what I've learned I decided to write some code using RxJS in a real-world project and things are going great.

Now I want to create a simple toggle button:

```
let btn = $('button')[0]
let clicks = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(btn, 'click')
               .map(function(clickEvent) {
                  // decide to return true/false
               })

clicks.subscribe(value => {
    // value is true or false
})
```

I can't get my head around this very simple exercise without using DOM methods in my stream. In fact, I just need the latest value from the stream, and then invert it (!!value);

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does your button carry state only through the DOM? In that case it will be impossible to retrieve that state without querying the DOM.

You could consider having your state out of the DOM and manipulate it without DOM functions. That said, you will have at some point to update the DOM state, but that you can do out of the stream in the observer.

Something like this :

```
var button_initial_state = false; // false for unchecked

var button_state$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(btn, 'click')
                                 .scan (function(current_state, event){
                                    return !current_state;
                                  }, button_initial_state)
                                 .startWith(button_initial_state);

button_state$.subscribe (function (state){
  // Code to set the button state in the DOM
})
```

Relevant documentation :

- [scan](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/scan.html)
- [startWith](http://rxmarbles.com/#startWith)

Comment: Cool, thanks! That's why I couldn't figure it out :). I will take a look at scan.

Comment: This gives an error in the RxVision Playground:
` TypeError: accumulator is not a function`

Comment: mmhh then try `.scan (button_initial_state, function(current_state, event){
                                    return !current_state;
                                  })`. The issue is that the signature of the function is different according to the version of Rxjs you are using. In one case, the seed is the first argument, in the other case, the seed is last. I don't which version RxVision is using, so check both possibilities

Comment: cool! They must be using Rxjs 2.x. Anyways you can go ahead and accept the answer

Comment: I wrote a blog post about this: https://www.themarketingtechnologist.co/create-a-simple-toggle-button-with-rxjs-using-scan-and-startwith/.

Comment: Why do you need the seed AND `startWith`?

Comment: you don't unless you do (!). i.e. make any changes that makes sense to you. `scan` does not emit an initial value (i.e. the seed is not an initial value for the stream, only for the computation), so if you would subscribe to the observable (without `startWith`) then you would see no immediate value, the first value you would see would be when the button is clicked. If you are happy with that, then take the `startWith` out.

Comment: Read your article. Interesting https://www.themarketingtechnologist.co/create-a-simple-toggle-button-with-rxjs-using-scan-and-startwith/

Comment: nice article, I like the progressive way by which you turn from imperative to functional.